# Display Multiple Values from Multiple Dropdowns Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display one value from each dropdown list to its corresponding text field, using Javascript. I've built up the drop-down menus with "matching" text fields, but seem to be unable to display any values once more than one drop down menu is in play.

```
<body>
<select name="DDcabinets" id="DDcabinets">
    <option value="">Select an option …</option>
    <option value="100">Dura Supreme</option>
    <option value="110">Lenape Village</option>
    <option value="120">Wellborn Forest</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="Vcabinets" id="Vcabinets" size="15" maxlength="5"/>
<br>
<select id="DDcountertop">
    <option value="">Select an option …</option>
    <option value="200">Granite</option>
    <option value="210">Quartz</option>
    <option value="220">Solid Surface</option>
    <option value="230">Laminate</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="Vcountertop" size="15" maxlength="5"/>
<br>
<select id="DDbacksplash">
    <option value="">Select an option …</option>
    <option value="300">Tile</option>
    <option value="310">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="Vbacksplash" size="15" maxlength="5"/>
```

And so forth. Any suggestions?

Edit: My javascript:

```
var select = document.getElementById('DDcabinets');
var input = document.getElementById('Vcabinets');
select.onchange = function() {
    input.value = select.value;
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your JavaScript code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure my JavaScript means nothing - I'm not familiar at all with Javascript (took some C++ and Java classes years ago but that's about it.)

Comment: Do you use the same variable names in JS for other your drop downs? Can you post full snippet at http://jsbin.com/ and post url here?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mayasi/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have your control IDs mixed up originally, but the following code works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var select1 = document.getElementById('DDcabinets');
        var input1 = document.getElementById('Vcabinets');
        select1.onchange = function () {
            input1.value = select1.value;
        };
        var select2 = document.getElementById('DDcountertop');
        var input2 = document.getElementById('Vcountertop');
        select2.onchange = function () {
            input2.value = select2.value;
        };
        var select3 = document.getElementById('DDbacksplash');
        var input3 = document.getElementById('Vbacksplash');
        select3.onchange = function () {
            input3.value = select3.value;
        };
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select id="DDcabinets">
        <option value="">Select an option …</option>
        <option value="100">Dura Supreme</option>
        <option value="110">Lenape Village</option>
        <option value="120">Wellborn Forest</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="Vcabinets" size="15" maxlength="5" />
    <br />
    <select id="DDcountertop">
        <option value="">Select an option …</option>
        <option value="200">Granite</option>
        <option value="210">Quartz</option>
        <option value="220">Solid Surface</option>
        <option value="230">Laminate</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="Vcountertop" size="15" maxlength="5" />
    <br />
    <select id="DDbacksplash">
        <option value="">Select an option …</option>
        <option value="300">Tile</option>
        <option value="310">Other</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="Vbacksplash" size="15" maxlength="5" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```